# How can I dynamically set checkboxes to be named variables?

Tags: variable

If I have a field of checkboxes, I'd like to be able to access them by the name of each checkbox as the variable name, and the 0 or 1 checked state as the value. Said variables need to be accessible beyond the `for` loop.

For example (doesn't work):

```
{% for checkbox in checkboxes %}
    {% set {{ checkbox }} = checkbox.selected %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've looked into things and seen answers mentioning `_context`, `attribute()`, and the like, but haven't been able to get anything to work.

In short, if I have a checkboxes field with a single checkbox whose name is `my_checkbox`, label is "My Checkbox", and is checked in an entry, I'd like to be able to use `{{ my_checkbox }}` to output "1" (i.e. it's checked).

Comment: You want to dynamically create Twig variables with the names based on selected labels in a checkbox field?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I _think_ in PHP it's called "variable variables"...?

Comment: I can't image the use-case for this. :)  But I don't think it'll be possible from Twig alone.  Are you comfortable with PHP/Craft plugins?

Comment: The use case was to be able to refer to the checkbox value outside the `for` loop. I've since reread the [docs for Checkboxes](https://craftcms.com/docs/checkboxes-fields) and found `entry.checkboxFieldHandle.contains('tequila')`. >.<

Comment: Ahh... would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had missed the `entry.checkboxFieldHandle.contains('tequila')` line in the docs, which allows me to access the checkbox values outside the `for` loop.